# jquery accordion on mouseover of image

Tags: jquery, hover, accordion, mouseover, jquery-tools

I trying to get an accordion of text to pop up on the mouseover of an image without clicking.

A working demo of text mouseover accordion [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/mouseover.html#)

```
<!-- JQuery --> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>       
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            event: "mouseover"
        });
    });
    </script>
```

and the html with the image

```
<div id="accordion">
   <a href="#"><img  src="images/icon_satellite.png"></img></a>
</div>
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
                                ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
                                amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
                                odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
                                </p>
                            </div>
```

but nothing happens and the accordion text is displayed

Getting this error:

> $("#accordion").accordion is not a function

Comment: See my answer for more info, but you are not including the jQuery UI framework, so there is no function `accordion()`.

Comment: Are you sure your links to your javascript are linked right? Also put a `/` in front of the link so your link doesn't get messed up if you are on a secondary page such as `domain.com/test/test` otherwise your javascript will link to `domain.com/test/js/jquery-1.7.1.js`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your document you are linking to the jQuery Tools framework, not the jQuery UI framework. I say this because your demo link goes to the jQuery UI site.

Are you getting an error like `[object] does not have method accordion`?

You can download a customized version of jQuery UI here: http://jqueryui.com/download. To get the smallest file-size possible, first click `Deselect All Components` at the top of the page, then select just the accordion widget from the widget list. The necessary parts of jQuery UI will be included in the download.

### Update

Giving your code another look-through I noticed you are improperly closing the image tag:

```
<a href="#"><img  src="images/icon_satellite.png"></img></a>
```

should be:

```
<a href="#"><img  src="images/icon_satellite.png" /></a>
```

Comment: Getting this error: $("#accordion").accordion is not a function index.html# Line 68

Comment: You need to include jQuery UI into your page, you are including jQuery Tools, which is un-related. They both need jQuery to function, but are different frameworks. Just my opinion, jQuery UI is a much better framework (it's like the official jQuery Tools).

Comment: @rd42 If you want to have jQuery UI hosted remotely in a CDN then Google has just that: http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/. But if all you want is the Accordion widget then you're better off downloading a customized version and loading it on your own server (see my answer for more info about this).

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because of the `</div>` after `<a href="#"></a><img  src="images/icon_satellite.png"></img></a>`

Comment: Still getting $("#accordion").accordion is not a function